# How to declare union inside a record structure?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I am trying to define the `TWaveFormatExtensible` type, but I am not sure if am I declaring correctly the `Samples` union. Here is the original declaration from header file (Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0):

```c
typedef struct {
    WAVEFORMATEX    Format;
    union {
        WORD wValidBitsPerSample;       /* bits of precision  */
        WORD wSamplesPerBlock;          /* valid if wBitsPerSample==0 */
        WORD wReserved;                 /* If neither applies, set to zero. */
    } Samples;
    DWORD           dwChannelMask;      /* which channels are */
                                        /* present in stream  */
    GUID            SubFormat;
}
```

And this is what I've tried:

```
type
  TWAVEFORMATEX = record
    wFormatTag: Word;
    nChannels: LongWord;
    nSamplesPerSec: Word;
    nAvgBytesPerSec: LongWord;
    nBlockAlign: Word;
    wBitsPerSample: Word;
    cbSize: Word;
  end;

  TWaveFormatExtensible = record
    Format: TWAVEFORMATEX;
    dwChannelMask: LongWord;
    SubFormat: Integer;
    case Word of
      0: (wValidBitsPerSample: Word;);
      1: (wSamplesPerBlock: Word;);
      2: (wReserved: Word;);
  end;
```

But that's not correct. How would one declare a union inside a record structure in Delphi?

Comment: IIRC, Delphi 7 predates the invention of `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`. What is stopping you from simply declaring it yourself in your own code?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: How to declare the union Samples?

Comment: P.S. `SubFormat` is of type `GUID` (`TGUID` in Delphi), not `Integer`. And member `nChannels` is of type `WORD` and `nSamplesPerSec` is `DWORD`. Except that you should preferrably use native types, e.g. `DWORD` members declare as `DWORD` types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fields of the structure must be in the same order as in the original (C++) declaration. But there's a problem: the original declaration puts the `Samples` variant in the middle of the record and that is not allowed in Delphi.

You can solve this by declaring the variant part as a separate record and then include that record as a field in the final structure.

```
TWaveFormatExtensibleSamples = record
case Word of
  0: (wValidBitsPerSample: Word;);
  1: (wSamplesPerBlock: Word;);
  2: (wReserved: Word;);
end;
```

and then construct the final structure:

```
TWaveFormatExtensible = record
  Format: TWAVEFORMATEX;
  Samples: TWaveFormatExtensibleSamples;
  dwChannelMask: DWORD;
  SubFormat: TGUID; 
end;
```

---

**edit**: The documentation for records with variant parts, state:

> A record type can have a variant part, which looks like a case statement. The variant part must follow the other fields in the record declaration.

This concerns variant parts without an enclosing record declaration.

However, as Remy Lebeau pointed out, a **record** with the variant part can be directly declared in the `TWaveFormatExtensible` declaration as part of the structure, in between other fields:

```
TWaveFormatExtensible = record
  Format: TWAVEFORMATEX;
  Samples: record
    case Word of
    0: (wValidBitsPerSample: Word;);
    1: (wSamplesPerBlock: Word;);
    2: (wReserved: Word;);
  end;
  dwChannelMask: DWORD;
  SubFormat: TGUID;
end;
```

So this can be used as well as the separately declared `TWaveFormatExtensibleSamples` record.

Comment: In this case, because `Samples` is not an anonymous union in the C declaration, you can merge `TWaveFormatExtensibleSamples` directly into `TWaveFormatExtensible`, it doesn't need to be separated: `TWaveFormatExtensible = record ... Samples: record case Word of ... end; ... end;`

Comment: Thank you @Remy for your comment